# Excel - removing duplicates based on a second column criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a dataset containing 3 columns.

1. Personal ID number
2. field of employment
3. months of working experience in the given field of employment

I have a large number of duplicates where a person has experience in two or more fields of employment. I want to narrow down my dataset so that no personal ID has a duplicate. The criteria being the field of employment where the individual has the most experience.

My dataset looks like this:

```
a                             b                 c
teacher                       ID99999           38 
teachers assistant            ID99999           6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a helper column in Column D.

1. Enter this array formula in D2: `=IF($C2=MAX(IF($A2=$A$2:$A$20,$C$2:$C$20,-1)),"Remain","Remove")`

**Note:** Enter the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter and fill down.

2. Filter column D by "Remove".
3. Finally, delete the filtered rows.

This formula will find the maximum months of experience in Column C for duplicate ID's, and mark those rows with "Remain".  Other rows with duplicate ID's are marked with "Remove".

[image]

Comment: Rajesh, you need to switch the words "Remove" and "Remain" in your formula. Otherwise, it's a pretty good answer.

Comment: @Bandersnatch,, suggest me the correction,,:-)

Comment: =IF( ... ),""Remain","Remove"). The two words are reversed now.  Look at your table. The result says to Remove the line A1|Teacher|120. That's the line to keep.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken initially criteria was different. Anyway, **Thanks a Lot**,, I've modified Formula as well as reloaded the Screen shot also.  Have Nice weekend :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sort C column from largest to smallest.

Now remove duplicate from Data Tab-> Remove Duplicates based on B Column.

[image]